# Htaccess redirects rules issue

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My server guys couldn't fix the issue I have. I'm running Wordpress on root folder. I don't want to have a folder language for English.

```
https://domain.com/account/t/

https://domain.com/fr/account/t/
```

are working fine, same for:

```
https://domain.com/auth/
```

But

```
https://domain.com/fr/account/t/myaccount/
```

is working fine but not

```
https://domain.com/account/t/myaccount/
```

Same for URL:

```
https://domain.com/fr/account/t/tests/
```

is working fine but not

```
https://domain.com/account/t/test/
```

It redirects to www.domain.com...

Would somebody have an idea? Here is my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/$ /auth/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/login$ /auth/login.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/logout$ /auth/logout.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/registration$ /auth/registration_form.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/password-forgotten$ /auth/forgot_form.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/reset$ /auth/reset.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/auth/activate$ /auth/activate.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/$ /account/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/$ /account/t/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/jobs/$ /account/t/jobs.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/myaccount/$ /account/t/myaccount.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/([^/]*)$ /account/t/?lang=$1&step=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/t/tests/$ /account/t/testspage.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/c/$ /account/c/?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/account/c/([^/]*)$ /account/c/?lang=$1&step=$2 [L]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `[^/]*` matches all even if it is not a language identifier.  Sometimes you'll match on something that needs to be part of the script name.

If you use this ...

```
RewriteRule ^((fr|de|es|it)/)?(.*) /$3.php?lang=$2
```

You match only one of the languages you support as listed.  Also, this generic approach means you only need 1 rewriterule, not 1 for each PHP script you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried but it's redirecting me to www.domain.com as well. Also I don't want the language identifier in the URL for main language...

Comment: If you are being redirected to www.domain.com, you must have something somewhere else, either in another .htaccess or the main httpd.conf or even in PHP.  The .htaccess you've given does not have "www" anywhere so it cannot be doing the redirect to a different domain.

Comment: Yes, understood that main language should not be in the URL.  That's why the pattern has the `?`, which means match 0 or 1 of the previous.  If the URL does not start with fr, de, es, OR it then $2 will be "", empty (implying "en").